# DNAT with port change not working

Tags: networking, nat

I'm using this command to establish NAT on my VM container:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d ${MAIN_IP} -p tcp --dport ${2} -j DNAT --to-destination ${SUBNET}${3}
```

with

- MAIN_IP being main server's global IP
- SUBNET being first three numbers of my VM subnet, e.g. "192.168.1."
- $2 being port I want to forward
- $3 being the last subnet segment, e.g. 20

This works fine for straight NATing.

But today I wanted to declare a DNAT to SSH port, so I set $2 to 5022 and $3 to 20:22, resulting in the following line, for clarity:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d ${MAIN_IP} -p tcp --dport 5022 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.20:22
```

Yet this one does not work: connections time out when I try to ssh to the VM.  Note that they do not time out when I don't use nat, so `ssh user@192.168.1.20` works just fine. It only doesn't work through NAT.

UFW is not enabled on container server. It listens to pretty much nothing so there's no need to close anything - or so I hope.

I'm assuming the DNAT rule is correct, so how do I determine what's blocking me?

Edit: output of nat table:

```
#iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             my-server         tcp dpt:2113 to:192.168.1.35
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             my-server         tcp dpt:2115 to:192.168.1.35

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Edit 2:
I'm temporarily solving the issue with having VM sshd listen to multiple ports. This way NAT works just fine.

Comment: We need to see things in the context of your overall iptables rule set. You need a corresponding FORWARD rule, for example `iptables -A FORWARD -i EXT_IF -o INT_IF -p tcp --dport 22 -d 192.168.111.20 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Uf, forward rule? I only have that one + nat masquerading. So far this has worked. I'm not behind computer right now, so i can't check, but i will asap